# Override form field templates in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, templating

I want to override base Symfony2 form input field, to add my class, but it does not work. Here is my code `AcmeDemoBundle:Form:fields.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_widget_simple %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}    class="testik_class"/>
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

In `config.yml`

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes:
        - 'AcmeDemoBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

But it does not work. In my form `class` attr still equal to `custom_form`. What I am doing wrong? Maybe I overiding incorect block ? 
Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Additionals:
Here is my form type:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('title', 'text', ['label' => 'form.title'])
        ->add('content', 'textarea', ['label' => 'form.content'])
    ;
}
```

Here is form template:

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

Insteresting that when I try override `textarea_widget` block or `integer_widget`, all works fine. Or when I try to add `data-*` attr to `simple_widget` it works fine too. But `class` not appends.

Comment: Post here code from your template where you use this block. I think that the main problem in incorrect block that you are overriding.

Comment: Hm... I dont use this in my form.html.twig where I render the form. If I understand right docs, it must hook automaticaly when I configure `config.yml` ...

Comment: Yes, you understand it right. But we need to know what form fields do you want to render and how do you do that?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov, I will post all code at a minute

Comment: Try to override `form_widget` block and you will know where is the problem.

Comment: are you sure that you using right Bundle?

Comment: @Trone, be sure all fine

Comment: Clear-cache may be helps you?

Comment: @Trone, Nope, does not... that was the first thing what I try to do...

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov, I can assign `data-*` attr, but not class....

Comment: post here your output (html code without any browser modifications)

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov, `<input data-test="hello" type="text" id="post_title" name="post[title]" required="required" class="custom_form">`, class I set to hello...

Comment: And change your template in your question that was used to generate this output. And what about second field? Post whole form.

Comment: The template is actually full, I use only form_widget to display all form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to override a class, you can simply do:

```
{{ form_widget(form, {'attr': {'class': 'testik_class'}}) }}
```

in your template, without using any specific form theme. This solves your problem and makes your code even more readable.

Or even when you build your form in PHP:

```
$builder->add('title', 'text', ['label' => 'form.title', 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'testik_class')])
```